# How to enable CORS in ASP.net Core WebAPI with deafult and own policy

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I would like to enable by EnableCors attribute my own "MyPolicy" for one controller and for the others I would like to use default policy. So in my configure services method I write

```
services.AddCors(options =>
{
    options.AddPolicy(name: "MyPolicy",
        builder => builder
            .WithOrigins("http://localhost:3000")
            .AllowCredentials()
            .AllowAnyMethod()
            .AllowAnyHeader());

    options.AddDefaultPolicy(
            builder => builder
            .AllowAnyOrigin()
            .AllowAnyMethod()
            .AllowAnyHeader());
});
```

and than in Configure method I just call:

```
app.UseCors();
```

it does not work as I expected. It's only define DefaultPolicy and the only way to use "MyPolicy" is to use them as:

```
app.UseCors("MyPolicy");
```

But in this case default policy does not work.
Is it possible to define own policies by AddPolicy and default policy by AddDefaultPolicy.

Comment: Which version of ASP.NET Core?

Comment: ASP.NET Core 2.2

Comment: Have you looked into https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/cors?view=aspnetcore-2.2#enable-cors-with-attributes-1 ?
The Attribute Based Approach in combination with the default CORS policy might fit you. Please Provide the controller code if you have tried to annotate the Routes with the CORS Attribute.

Comment: I read this before but now I try to not UseCorse in Configure method as in ms doc listening. I use only attribute approach in controllers and it's work as I expected. I wanted to combine UseCorse in configure method and attribute approach but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you would like to use many own policies and default policy the solution is to define in configureservices:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddCors(options =>
    {
        options.AddDefaultPolicy(
            builder =>
            {
               
                builder.WithOrigins("http://example.com",
                                    "http://www.contoso.com");
            });

        options.AddPolicy("AnotherPolicy",
            builder =>
            {
                builder.WithOrigins("http://www.contoso.com")
                                    .AllowAnyHeader()
                                    .AllowAnyMethod();
            });

    });

    services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2);
}
```

and use policies through EnableCorsAttribute like this:

```
  // GET api/values
    [EnableCors("AnotherPolicy")]
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult<IEnumerable<string>> Get()
    {
        return new string[] { "green widget", "red widget" };
    }
```

. In this case do not call UseCors method of app IApplicationBuilder object in configure method startup class.

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
{
    if (env.IsDevelopment())
    {
        app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
    }
    else
    {
        app.UseHsts();
    }
    //Do not use this method:
    //app.UseCors();

    app.UseHttpsRedirection();
    app.UseMvc();
}
```